# Events wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'd like to understand how to do a specific task. I was trying to set up event tables in wxWidgets and ran into an issue with their behaviour.

I set up some code in one class:

```
void TopRightPanel::OnSelChanged(wxTreeEvent& event)
{
    wxTreeItemId item = event.GetItem();
    TreeItemData* data = (TreeItemData *) GetItemData(item);

    if(data != NULL)
    {

        particleSystemManager->SetSelectedParticleSystem(data->particleSystem); 
    }

 }
```

This works fine and has the right values as expected. My problem with this though is that it's self contained and I want the class above it in the hierarchy to read the treeCtrl's action and make changes to all aspects of the U.I. So I tried this:

```
void Window::OnSelChanged(wxTreeEvent& event)
{
    wxTreeItemId item = event.GetItem();
    TreeItemData* data = (TreeItemData *) topRightPanel->GetItemData(item);//item.m_pItem.//m_MyTreeCtrl->GetItemData(itemId);*/

    if(data != NULL)
    {
        particleSystemManager.SetSelectedParticleSystem(data->particleSystem); 

    }
}
```

Now I get an unhandled exception when topRightPanel->GetItemData(data) is called. The topRightPanel it uses doesn't seem to be updated and seems to be pointing to data before it's enstantuated in the class' constructor. Is there anyway I can get round this?

Edit:

I declare the event table like so:

```
#if USE_GENERIC_TREECTRL
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TopRightPanel, wxGenericTreeCtrl)
#else
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TopRightPanel, wxTreeCtrl)
#endif
EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED(TopRightPanel_Ctrl, Window::OnSelChanged)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

and I then declare the table in the header using DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE.

Comment: This code looks like it should work, and from what you describe it sounds like the problem might be in C++ object construction order or initialization of the topRightPanel pointer (which I'm assuming is a member of Window).  I also assume you've used topRightPanel in a similar fashion elsewhere without crashes?

Comment: @jstine yes it works absolutely fine everywhere else. If I put a breakpoint in my Window class' update, the topRightPanel has values indicating it's correctly initialized, if I check with a breakpoint in the OnSelChanged method the value is completely different...

Comment: Ok, I think the problem here might be the way wxWidgets force-casts objects when you create event handles.  I used to run into problems where wx would invoke (for example) the Window::OnSelChanged() handler, but the actual object (eg, this-> pointer) was the TopRightPanel instance.  Since both objects share the same base window object, a lot of stuff still works that way.  Pretty much the only things that will be wrong are things specific to your Window definituon.

Comment: I'd give a better answer on how to make sure you're avoiding that (it has to do with somewhat terse manual event registration jargon) ... but I haven't used wx in a while and don't feel qualified to write one up beyond what I've already said.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** use the same class name in the event table macros that you used in `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE`. IOW, your handler must be defined in `Window` event table and not in `TopRightPanel` event table. As tree events are `wxCommandEvents`, they are propagated upwards to the parent so if `Window` contains the tree control, this will work. Otherwise, e.g. if they are siblings, you would have to use `Connect()` as indicated in another answer.

(Re)reading [the event handling overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html) would be highly recommended.

Comment: I ended up solving this using Connect(). It seemed a cleaner method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how do you connect this event handler but the problem is almost surely there and not in the code you show. If you're using `Connect()`, make sure that you pass the pointer to `Window` object as its last argument, otherwise you end up calling a method of `Window` class on `TopRightPanel` object with the unsurprisingly catastrophic consequences.

If you're sure that you do call the method on the right object, then the only other explanation I see is that you don't initialize `topRightPanel` before the first event of this type is generated. If this is the case, the simplest solution is to initialize the pointer to `NULL` and set it correctly at the end of the initialization code. And, of course, check for the pointer being non-NULL in the event handler.

Comment: I'm using event tables, I'll amend the question.

Comment: Question now amended. I don't use Connect at all... Should I be?

Comment: No, if you are using event tables, then it should be fine. Can it be so that you have 2 or more tree controls with same Window ID? What happens if you use event.GetEventObject() and cast it to wxTreeCtrl * and then use that pointer to wxTreeCtrl for obtaining data? Can you confirm that pointer returned by GetEventObject() is the same as pointer to your topRightPanel?

Comment: @T-Rex Ok that works. I did as you suggested and replaced the topRightPanel in my code with treeCtrl I got from GetEventObject(). The this pointer seems to be also be the same as the topRightPanel in that method. I'm really wanting it to be called through the Window not the treeCtrl so persumably I'll have to find a way of changing the handler?

Comment: Would be better if you upload the code somewhere and send me the link. I can take a look at it. However your code in the question looks fine for me.

Comment: Another idea: I got exceptions several times in working code in my projects and solved this by cleaning wxWidgets libs and rebuilding the whole set of wx libraries. You can try to clean wxWidgets solution, rebuild libs, then clean your projects's solution and rebuild again.